# Does git rebase and or git merge create filed with conflicts marked up?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

After I got message about existing conflicts, I found that files with conflicts contain marks like

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

or

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Is this correct? What is the name of this file format?

Comment: Those marks indicate conflicting areas. Git displays how your code looks on both branches your are trying to merge. You have to resolve those conflicts in order to be able to merge.

Comment: Ya, I understand this. But I wish to open this file in some GUI tool and hence wish to know beforehead, it is supports it.

Comment: I personally use `git mergetool` to resolve conflicts. You can specify which tool to use, like meld: `git mergetool --tool=meld`

Comment: @VadimSirbu does `meld` read this file? how would you know, that `meld` tool can understand such a file? how to ask, if `Clion` can understand such a file?

Comment: Use `emacs`. It has good mode for Git.

Answer (score 0):

Conflict marks `<<<<`, `====` and `>>>>` could be a result of a conflict in many `git` commands: `rebase`, `merge`, `cherry-pick`, `apply`. The result is still a text file and you can open it in any text editor. E.g, I usually use `vim` instead of `mergetool`.